# How to sign code using .pem/.spc/.csr file?

Tags: asp.net, .net, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I have purchased Code Signing certificate and got one .pem file which contains certificate format and another one is .spc file. I want to know the process of signing code using these files.
Earlier I have signed code using self signed certificate using .cer file(Certificate file) and .pvk file(Private key file), but don’t know how to sign code using .pem and .spc file?

Please suggest any tutorial/document for doing the same for xap file?